Induced map on functor category is fully faithful
Hi I need to show the following:
Let $L,R$ be two adjoint functors,
$C
\underset{R}
{
   \stackrel{L}
   {
      \underset{\longleftarrow}
      {\stackrel{\longrightarrow}{\scriptsize\perp}}
   }
}
D
$
. Furthermore suppose $R$ is fully faithful. Let $E$ be another category. Then:
$L: Fun(D,E) \to Fun(C,E)$ given on objects by $F \mapsto FL$ and on morphisms $\eta_x \mapsto (\eta L)_x = \eta_{Lx}$ is fully faithful.
This means, that I need to show that for two functors $F,G: D \to E$ the maps:
$ Hom_{Fun}(F,G) \to Hom_{Fun}(FL,GL) $ given by $L$ (as above) is a biejction. I tried in some way to construct a invers map with the help of my other given functor $R$ but my problem is that $F$ is always in front of everything so I cant use efficently the given property of adjunction (as for that I need $L$ in front.
One thing I tried was to use the following map as invers taking $\gamma_y :FLy \to GLy \mapsto (\gamma R)_y = \gamma_{Ry}: FLRy \to GLRy$. But I have no clue if this is even a invers map or how to show it. Is this the right approach?

Call the functor $F \mapsto FL$ $L^$. Then, likewise, there is a functor $R^:Fun(C,E) \to Fun(D,E)$, $G \mapsto GR$. Show that $R^* \dashv L^*$ with unit $G\eta:G \to L^*R^*G=GRL$ and counit $F\epsilon:R^*L^F=FLR \to F$ and conclude that $L^$ is fully faithful.

Note also that a right (or dually, left) adjoint is fully faithful if and only if the counit (or unit, respectively) is an isomorphism.

Are you sure that R* is left adjoint to G* if I try to show it I come up with Hom(RG,F) = Hom(GR,F) and here I have to stop because the R is always on the right sight, moreover even if it would be why should it follow that L is fully faithfull.

$R^$ is left adjoint to $L^$, not $G^$; see precomposite adjunction. Your equation between Hom-sets is nonsense. You're trying to show that $L^$ is fully faithful, not $L$.

See @GeoffreyTrang's comment: a right adjoint functor is fully faithful iff the counit of its adjunction is an isomorphism. This should be enough information to get you on the right track.

It's easier to build the precomposite adjunction in terms of unit and counit, as on the nLab. You can then "reverse engineer" what the Hom-isomorphism does if you like.

These are answers to the question, not just a comment. Comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See How do comments work for more information. Therefore, please post your answers as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list. Generally speaking, please notice that MSE is not a discussion forum.

We may assume that $D$ is a full reflective subcategory of $C$, that $R : D \to C$ is the inclusion, and hence that $L : C \to D$ is the reflector.  This is not necessary for the proof, but it simplifies the exposition a bit. It may also help to carry out the proof in the special case $\mathbf{Ab} \subseteq \mathbf{Grp}$, the general case works exactly the same.
We denote the unit of the adjunction by $\eta$, so it is given by morphisms $\eta(c) : c \to L(c)$, where $c \in C$. This is an isomorphism when $c \in D$. For every morphism $f : c \to d$ (where $c \in C$, $d \in D$) there is a unique morphism $f' : L(c) \to d$ with $f' \circ \eta(c) = f$. Notice that $\eta(L(c))$ is an isomorphism with $\eta(L(c)) = L(\eta(c))$.
Assume $F,G : D \to E$ are two functors. We need to show that a morphism* $\beta : F \circ L \to G \circ L$ is induced by a unique morphism $\alpha : F \to G$.
Well, a morphism $\beta : F \circ L \to G \circ L$ consists of morphisms $\beta(c) : F(L(c)) \to G(L(c))$, natural in $c \in C$. In particular, for every $d \in D$ we get a morphism
$$\beta'(d) : F(d) \cong F(L(d)) \to G(L(d)) \cong G(d),$$
natural in $d$. In other words, we define
$$\beta'(d) := G(\eta(d))^{-1} \circ \beta(d) \circ F(\eta(d)).$$
This yields a morphism $\beta' : F \to G$.
Conversely, if $\alpha : F \to G$ is a morphism, for all $c \in C$ we get a morphism $\alpha(L(c)) : F(L(c)) \to G(L(c))$, thus a morphism $\alpha' : F \circ L \to G \circ L$. So we have
$$\alpha'(c) = \alpha(L(c)).$$
Let us check that these constructions are inverse to each other.
Let $\alpha : F \to G$ be a morphism, then by definition $(\alpha')'$ is given by
$$(\alpha')'(d)  = G(\eta(d))^{-1} \circ \alpha(L(d)) \circ F(\eta(d))$$
for $d \in D$. Since $\alpha$ is natural with respect to the isomorphism $\eta(d) : d \to L(d)$, this composition is equal to $\alpha(d)$. This shows $(\alpha')'= \alpha$.
Let $\beta : F \circ L \to G \circ L$ be a morphism. Then by definition, $(\beta')'$ is given by
$$(\beta')'(c) = G(\eta(L(c))^{-1} \circ \beta(L(c)) \circ F(\eta(L(c))$$
for $c \in C$. Since $\eta(L(c)) = L(\eta(c))$, and $\beta$ is natural, this is equal to
$$\dotsc = G(L(\eta(c))^{-1} \circ \beta(L(c)) \circ F(L(\eta(c)) = \beta(c).$$
Therefore, we have $(\beta')' = \beta$.
*aka natural transformation.
PS: The proof posted by Geoffrey Trang in the comments is much more elegant. I hope he posts this as an answer as well. This here is just an alternative which is more "hands down".

thank you very much for your answer (which is really nice written), I understood the proof. Now I would like to understand it in the general case. I dont get how I can do the first direction in general i.e instead of F(d) = F(Ld) here I need a morphism (isomorphism) which is natural but I dont come up with a morphism from d to Ld (analogly at the end G(Ld) to G(d), moreover its not clear in general for my why \beta '(d) = \beta (d) (or problably in general isomorphic?)

I have updated the answer. Please check.
